# How to get a quote and swap on 0x with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, 0x

I'm trying to make a simple swap from 10 USDC to 10 USDT using 0x API quote.

I'm doing this:

```
import type { UnsignedTransaction } from '@ethersproject/transactions'
import { Web3Provider } from '@ethersproject/providers'

const provider = new Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

const [address] = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' })

const res = await fetch('https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyAmount=1000000&buyToken=USDT&sellToken=USDC')

const quote = await res.json()

// not sure what to do next?
```

What should be the next step to perform a swap? Using a `Web3Provider`.

Reference: https://0x.org/docs/guides/swap-tokens-with-0x-api#selling-erc20-tokens

Answer (score 0):

0x API returns a JSON object with standard ethereum transaction fields already populated. You should follow your [web3 library's guide](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-sendTransaction) for sending transaction objects. Depending on whether you pass in `takerAddress` as part of your request, you may also have to populate the `gas` fied on your own.

Don't forget to set appropriate token allowances in advance.

Comment: Could you please show a code example with ethers.js code? I'm not getting what I should put in `types` and `domain` for 0x Protocol.

Comment: Not sure where you're seeing that. You shouldn't need to worry about those concepts if you're just trying to fill a swap quote.

Answer (score 0):

Since the response of /quote endpoint is already a transaction, I think the line you have to add is :

```
const mintTx = await provider.sendTransaction(quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

just seeing this, this setup worked for me, I pulled in the signer with the wagmi lib (useSigner hook):

```
await signer?.sendTransaction({
                        from: yourConnectedAddress,
                        to: quote.to,
                        data: quote.data,
                        value: quote.value,
                        gasLimit: quote.estimatedGas,
                    });
```